# Path in instructions "CONCATE... PREPARE... EXECUTE... "

Tags: mysql, path, execute, macro-variable

I'm having a problem with MySQL. To put it in context, I'm in charge of **migrating my company's codes from Oracle to MySQL** and I'm having quite a few problems with macro variables: the only solution I've found is to use concat, then prepare and execute, but that makes us lose a lot of readability... By the way, if you have a better alternative on this point, don't hesitate!

Having said that, in general, the "concate.... PREPARE... EXECUTE" instructions allow me to do whatever I want, except when translating path macros...

When I want to use these instructions with source or tee, I get error messages and despite several weeks of searching I can't find a solution. Does anyone have a solution?

I've included some code examples below

Example 1:

I want to automate
source //data_file/data_test/test_source_fic_a_import.sql;
when I run it like this no worries but when I do :

```
set @rep_ts := '//data_file/data_test/';
SET @req_test_source := CONCAT("source ", @rep_ts, "test_source_fic_a_import.sql ;");
PREPARE prepa_test_source FROM @req_test_source; EXECUTE prepa_test_source; DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepa_test_source;
```

I get the following error message :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near [...]

Example 2 :

It's the same when I run :

```
tee //data_file/data_test/test_tee.txt;
use basecommune;
select count(*)
from test_squelbyan;
notee
```

it works but when I try

```
set @rep_ts := '//data_file/data_test/';
SET @req_test_tee := CONCAT("tee ", @rep_ts, "test_tee.txt;");
PREPARE prepa_test_tee FROM @req_test_tee; EXECUTE prepa_test_tee; DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepa_test_tee;
```

I get :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tee [...]

Answer (score 1):

`source` and `tee` are mysql client builtin commands. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html

Those builtin commands are not recognized by MySQL's SQL parser, and they cannot be run by a prepared statement.

You can only run such commands in the mysql client, for example at the `mysql>` prompt, or in an SQL script that is run by the mysql client.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... To your knowledge, isn't there an equivalence? With Oracle, we use macro variables a lot and are used to changing folders easily. We often use tool tables and routine scripts in several sub-folders to prevent our codes from being spaciophagous.

Comment: You can use the `tee` command in the mysql client to save query results, but that works only in that mysql client shell. If you want to do the same thing in your own application, you must write code to fetch query results and write lines to a file.